# Show quantities buttons next to add to cart in Shop Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the quantity selectors next to the add to cart button in AJAX on every page. My issue is when I click on add to cart button, even if the quantity is 2,3 or 10 it only adds up 1 and not the amount that is in the quantity field. My script below:

```
function shop_page_add_quantity_field() {

    /** @var WC_Product $product */
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

    if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() && 'variable' != $product->get_type() && $product->is_purchasable() ) {
        woocommerce_quantity_input( array( ‘min_value’ => 1, ‘max_value’ => $product->backorders_allowed() ? ” : $product->get_stock_quantity() ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'shop_page_add_quantity_field', 20, 999 );

/**
 * Add required JavaScript.
 */
function shop_page_quantity_add_to_cart_handler() {

    wc_enqueue_js( '
        $(".woocommerce .products").on("click", ".quantity input", function() {
            return false;
        });
        $(".woocommerce .products").on("change input", ".quantity .qty", function() {
            var add_to_cart_button = $(this).parents( ".product" ).find(".add_to_cart_button");

            // For AJAX add-to-cart actions
            add_to_cart_button.data("quantity", $(this).val());

            // For non-AJAX add-to-cart actions
            add_to_cart_button.attr("href", "?add-to-cart=" + add_to_cart_button.attr("data-product_id") + "&quantity=" + $(this).val());
        });

        // Trigger on Enter press
        $(".woocommerce .products").on("keypress", ".quantity .qty", function(e) {
            if ((e.which||e.keyCode) === 13) {
                $( this ).parents(".product").find(".add_to_cart_button").trigger("click");
            }
        });
    ' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'shop_page_quantity_add_to_cart_handler' );
```

Could you help me on the above? I would really appreciate any help.